# what api is this test written in?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

code snippet:

```
  describe('GetList', () => {
    it('should respond with 200 Success', function* () {
      let res = yield api
        .get(apiPath)
        .set({ })
        .expect(200)
        .endAsync();

      res.body.forEach((item) => {
        item.should.have.property('appName');
        item.should.have.property('appDomain');
      });
```

I need to write tests in the framework in which the above code is written.
if you can hint what framework it is, maybe I can read api docs and write one myself.
what I have to do is write a test that compares two arrays returned from `api` calls.
from npm settings it seems it use mocha and istanbul as testing framework.

Comment: That looks like Jasmine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like [Jasmine Behavior-Driven JavaScript](http://jasmine.github.io/).

Perhaps it's [Mochajs](https://mochajs.org/) as it has `should.have`. Jasmine, at least on the 2.4 documentation doesn't mention the `should.have` API.

Could you see what's included when this test is executed? Or the `package.json` file. Likely at the `devDependencies`.

Comment: it's not jasmin(expect() fails), but I think it is mochajs. but mochajs just says it can use any testing library you want! I think it's shouldjs.

Comment: Often times it's 'chai'